# what is lambda and z in textstat_collocations() in R

Tags: r, text-mining, quanteda

I am new to NLP. I was reading through the notes in https://tutorials.quanteda.io/ for doing text mining, and I came across a part which I don't understand.

Assuming I have some datasets and I performed textstat_collocations() on it. Below is the result:

[image]

What does the value of lambda and z represents? I try reading them on the documentation, but I don't really get what it means. Thank you very much for helping me

Comment: The explanation for `lambda` and `z` is found in detail in lines 34-69 in the [documentation](https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda.textstats/blob/master/R/textstat_collocations.R#L34).

Comment: This is more of a Cross-Validated type question. But since I'm (slowly) working on a paper explaining this, could make more sense to wait for that.